# JQuery Mobile works only sometimes

Tags: jquery, mobile, loading, freeze

I have a JQuery Mobile Page where works only sometimes. Otherwise i have a blank Page or a loading icon look like is hanged on (only on mobile devices). Click to "Ändern" on a mobile device to see the issue.

The URL of the Page is here: http://tinyurl.com/test60500

I have no idea what is gonna wrong.

Can you help me, thanks :)

Comment: Please post related codes here, and make a JSFiddle.

Comment: working fine in my device...

Comment: It asks for translate..!

Comment: The Code is on the Link above. The issue is only on Mobile Devices. I have made the URL shorter: http://tinyurl.com/test60500  . You need JS Fiddle?

Comment: Working fine on my htcv one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar problem just link the .js and .css like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

even if your present code starts worikng. the jquery mobile icons will not be displayed unless you link it to this source.

Comment: OK Thanks, it was a conflict with the JQuery UI.